# Format of JXLS not shifting correctly with empty list

Tags: jxls

The format of the JXLS result is not being "shifted" when you have an empty list before.

Please refer to the template and output files here: https://files.fm/u/e68wgub2

```
List<String> NON_EMPTY_LIST = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
List<String> EMPTY_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

String EMPTY_LIST_NAME = "emptyList";
String NON_EMPTY_LIST_NAME = "nonEmptyList";

String INPUT_FILE_PATH = "./Test_Template.xls";
String OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = "./Output.xls";

InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;

try {
    is = new FileInputStream(new File(INPUT_FILE_PATH));
    os = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.putVar(NON_EMPTY_LIST_NAME, NON_EMPTY_LIST);
    context.putVar(EMPTY_LIST_NAME, EMPTY_LIST);

    JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);

    is.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    System.out.println(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH + " created.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the code you see two lists: an empty list with name "EMPTY_LIST_NAME" and a non-empty list with name "NON_EMPTY_LIST_NAME". In the template you have A8 having a large cell format. In the result, you still have A8 with the large cell format. But not the cell A8 should have this format in the result, but A7, since because of the empty list, the results shifted up.

I get the same results when the cells are shifted down instead of up. Using jxls 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is how jxls designed - it shifts cells based on template area changes comparing with result area. Since list is empty, resulting area height is 0 but original is 1, thats why it shifted up I guess.

I can suggest you on creating context to check if list is empty and insert to list string like "No data" or just empty string to make cell processed and kept.

Comment: The cell content is shifted up, this is correct, but the cell format is *not* shifted up, so this seems a bug.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:
This is a bug. It should be corrected in the new jxls version: 
https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/100/cell-format-not-being-correctly-shifted